# then() block of promise does not wait for internal await

Tags: angular, promise

I have the following methods:

```
  this.skickPlayerService.loadSkick().then(
  (skick) => {
    var skickBlob = skick as Blob;
  },
  (error) => {}
);
```

The async method calls looks as follow:

```
async loadSkick(): Promise<any> {
try {
  return await this.graphClient
    .api('/me/drive/items/25647924903216B8%21227697')
    .get(async (err, res) => {
      if (err) {
        return;
      }
      return await fetch(res['@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl']).then(
        async function (response) {
          return await response.blob(); // I need the call to wait until this is executed
        }
      );
    });
  } catch (error) {}
}
```

The problem is that loadSkick() returns when .then is executed, but the value is still null because the next internal call "return await response.blob();" hasn't been executed yet.

I need to return to the caller only once the result of the  return await response.blob(); is executed

Comment: It appears that `this.graphClient.api('/me/drive/items/25647924903216B8%21227697').get(...)` does not return a promise (since you're passing it a normal callback) so `await` doesn't do anything useful in this case.

Comment: How can i make this to work as expected?

Comment: Please post a link to the graphClient library documentation.

Comment: Documentation: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-javascript#documentation
However I am using this integration with angular:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/tutorials/angular?tutorial-step=4

Comment: Just edited the link to get direct access to the documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the doc, it looks like this should work:

```
async loadSkick(): Promise<any> {
    const res = await this.graphClient
        .api('/me/drive/items/25647924903216B8%21227697')
        .get();
    const response = await fetch(res['@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl']);
    return response.blob();
}
```

The caller to `loadSkick()` will have to use the returned promise with either `await` or `.then()` to get the final result.

Comment: you are awesome. Thanks.